# What does the expression "V+F" (or "V&F") mean on a photography web site?

Tags: terminology, 500px

I was reading comments on my photos posted at 500px.com (for example, at http://500px.com/photo/21988337 and http://500px.com/photo/21997241).

Read a few comments that say V+F or V&F, what are they? what is their meaning?

Comment: I think this should stay open. 500px is a photography site and the question is related to using it. That's not really off topic here, IMO, since a lot of us use sites like this.

Comment: Great photos. If you made them a little larger, they'd make great screen wallpaper too (meant as a compliment).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Voted and Favourited.

From reading the 3rd comment. This is a 500px notation/abbreviation, not a photography term.

Nice pics, BTW.

Comment: It's a photography term in as much as 500px is a dedicated photography site and the users are using the term in respect to the photos they see.

Comment: JoanneC: Do you want me to change my answer? Edit it if you like... The only thing that comes to mind in actual photography would be _view finder_. None the less I still stated that it is shorthand for the 500px site and wasn't voting it down. I was just saying that it's not a photography term.

Answer (score 3):

V+F or V/F or V&F is just "Voted Favorited" which means, of course, that your picture was voted and favorited by the user :)

Cheers"